# Calling a variable outside of a function

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, api

I'd like to input `result` value into the `email` variable. but I can't call the `email` variable outside of the function. what do I do wrong here?

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction.DigitalChecksChargeController.getContactEmail}',
    '{!AcctSeed__Cash_Disbursement__c.AcctSeed__Vendor__c}', 
           function(result, event) {
                //console.log(result);
                  document.getElementById('{!$Component.emailInp}').innerHTML = " ";
                  document.getElementById('{!$Component.emailInp}').innerHTML = result;

                  var email = result // THIS VARIABLE CAN NOT GET CALLED FROM OUSIDE OF THE FUNCTION ?? 
          }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, the `result` variable is only visible to that function. If you want to use it elsewhere, you need to declare a top level variable outside the function and assign it to the values inside the function. Example:

```
// Declare a global variable 
var email;

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction.DigitalChecksChargeController.getContactEmail}',
    '{!AcctSeed__Cash_Disbursement__c.AcctSeed__Vendor__c}', 
           function(result, event) {
                //console.log(result);
                  document.getElementById('{!$Component.emailInp}').innerHTML = " ";
                  document.getElementById('{!$Component.emailInp}').innerHTML = result;

                  email = result;
          }
);

// now you will have the result stored in the email global variable and it's available elsewhere in the code
```